# How to give custom location to error in jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I want to place an error for `logemail` in `#logemailerror` and error for `logpass` in `#logpasserror`.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  /* validation */
  $("#login-form").validate({
    rules: {
      password: {
        required: true,
      },
      user_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      password: {
        required: "please enter your password"
      },
      user_email: "please enter your email address",
    },
    submitHandler: submitForm
  });
```

```html
<div id="login_form" style='display:none'>
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width:400px; text-align:center;">
    <div class="modal-content login-modal">
      <div class="modal-header login-modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="loginModalLabel">Log-In</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="text-center">
          <form id="login" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="user_login">

            <input type="hidden" name="module">
            <div id="error">
              <!-- error will be shown here ! -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:8%;">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="logemail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
              </div>
              <div id="logemailerror"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:8%;">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="password" name="logpass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <br />
              </div>
              <div id="logpasserror"></div>
            </div>
            <input value="Login" name="Login" id="submit" class="btn  bt-login" type="submit" style="margin-left:8%; width:92%" />
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="login-modal-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                  <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                  <a href="#" id="forget_tab" class="forgetpass-tab"> Forgot password? </a> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                  <a href="#" id="signup_tab" class="signup-tab"> Sign-Up </a> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me. How could this be achieved? Whenever I try to use `errorplacement` the javascript stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the documentation for **[errorPlacement](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement)**

```js
$("#login-form").validate({
  rules: {
    password: {
      required: true,
    },
    user_email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    password: {
      required: "please enter your password"
    },
    user_email: "please enter your email address",
  },
  submitHandler: submitForm,

  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "logemail") {
      $("#logemailerror").append(error);
    } else if (element.attr("name") == "logpass") {
      $("#logpasserror").append(error);
    }
  }

});
```